# Share a folder with Dropbox users but prevent them from modifying?

Tags: dropbox

I share a folder with 4 users of Dropbox and I just want them to see automatically the files I’m adding, I don’t want them to be able to modify or delete anything inside it.

So, how can I unauthorize them from modification?

P.S.: I know already about the “share-link” option, but this way the users don’t see automatically the added files.

Answer (score 10):

You can't set permissions for shared folders in Dropbox.

This feature has been requested for three years, as has received almost 150k votes in [Votebox](https://www.dropbox.com/votebox/22/sharing-permissions), but Dropbox hasn't implemented it yet.

Comment: There are some good reasons for not implementing it, though. If the files are synced and not downloaded, then they *are* still files on the user's computer, and the user *can* edit them. (Even if they are marked as read-only.) This has a potential to cause a lot of confusion for users. The power of Dropbox is that the files are just regular files on your system. This would somewhat chip away at that model.

Answer (score 1):

My own solution for this is to have a private backup of the shared files (i.e. in some .rar file that is not shared to other users).

Answer (score 1):

Or... Instead of sharign the folder, share a link to it. The files in the link also auto-update with your changes, so you don't have to give "updated links" all the time, but also, they remain read-only. People will be able to view & download the files, but not modify or delete them.